# installing Ubuntu alongside win10.... i'm deleting or making unable "windows advanced startup options"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

**My primary OS:** Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

**Want to install:** latest version of Ubuntu

**Problem:** Ubuntu or GRUB disables Windows Advanced Startup Options and I need them.

[image: Windows boot manager options]

Comment: Here is a good start: [How to get to Windows 7 Advanced Boot Options from GRUB](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1683031), also have in mind  the following: [How to Access Advanced Startup Options in Windows 10 or 8](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229)

Comment: Windows does something called <preparing automatic repair> when i need repair the windows boot, having installed GRUB, there are problems?

Comment: After passing the GRUB you can press F8 to get the Advanced Boot Options, and there are many ways to get them, see the previous link.

Comment: i know, one thing is access to the "advanced boot options", other thing is <preparing atomatic repair...> may be damaged by x or y reason.